# XSLT 1.0 Handling of empty elements when outputting a comma separated list

Tags: xslt

I am new to stackoverflow and would appreciate any help. 
It is a XSLT 1.0 problem I have encountered and I'm sure there is a simple solution I just can't find it.

I have top `book` element containing many chapters that each have a title:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Book>
  <Chapter>
    <Title>ONE</Title>
  </Chapter>
  <Chapter>
    <Title>TWO</Title>
  </Chapter>
  <Chapter>
    <Title></Title>
  </Chapter>
  <Chapter>
    <Title>FOUR</Title>
  </Chapter>
</Book>
```

I want to transform the above into one element called CSV-Title-List. It seemed easy enough until the case of an empty Title occurred. I get an unexpected comma using the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Book">
      <CSV-Title-List>
      <xsl:for-each select="Chapter/Title">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
          <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </CSV-Title-List>
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My question is, how can I cleanly check the next Chapter/Title for a null string before outputting the comma with the above stylesheet. There must be a better way? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks to any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Chapter[normalize-space(Title)]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Chapter">
  <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">,</xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Book>
  <Chapter>
    <Title>ONE</Title>
  </Chapter>
  <Chapter>
    <Title>TWO</Title>
  </Chapter>
  <Chapter>
    <Title></Title>
  </Chapter>
  <Chapter>
    <Title>FOUR</Title>
  </Chapter>
</Book>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
ONE,TWO,FOUR
```

**When the same transformation is applied on a different XML document -- in which the first `/*/Chapter/Title` has a white-space-only string value**:

```
<Book>
  <Chapter>
    <Title>     </Title>
  </Chapter>
  <Chapter>
    <Title>TWO</Title>
  </Chapter>
  <Chapter>
    <Title></Title>
  </Chapter>
  <Chapter>
    <Title>FOUR</Title>
  </Chapter>
</Book>
```

**again the correct, wanted result is produced**:

```
TWO,FOUR
```

Comment: Thank-you Dimitre, this works well. I see the strip-spce elements all is very important there. Simple and effective solution Cheers :)

Comment: @GaryCarlton, You are welcome. And you are very observant! Yes, `xsl:strip-space` is very important here -- take it away and the code no longer works correctly, because of the whitespace-only text nodes siblings of `/*/Chapter` -- they also count in calculating `position()`

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Your last statement there is incorrect- the calculation of position() in your code refers to the `Chapter` element, which is of course not stripped out, as it contains the `Title` element.

Comment: @Flynn1179, If you have read well, you would have seen that the comment is about the "whitespace-only text node siblings" of `/*/Chapter` -- not about any `Chapter element.

Comment: @GaryCarlton, I have edited and modified this solution with a more precise one -- please use the latter.

Comment: I am very happy with all the answers. Really thanks for all the help guys. I am amazed by the fast responses and competition to serve the best answer. Was struggling to get this correct and now it is I am intrigued to learn more XSLT.

Comment: @Gary, You are welcome. For good XSLT/XPath resources, please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/341589/36305

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works even if your first `Title` element is blank.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

 <xsl:template match="Book">
  <xsl:variable name="booklist">
   <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring($booklist,2)" />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Title/text()">
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:copy />
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It also doesn't use an explicit conditional, simply prepending a comma in front of EVERY value, storing the result in a variable, and outputting that variable from the 2nd character onwards (skipping the first comma).

Comment: Good call Flynn1179, thank-you very much. The first chapter could be null so this provides the expected output for that case. There is much talent at stackoverflow.